# Index Seek on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, index

Sorry folks if this sounds obvious. But does index seek always work on index pages not data pages? If so, which I think it is, it can only be used on its own if the output list are the same as index fields/covering . As a result, if a non-index field is needed for the output , it is neither not used by a query engine at all or used with Key/RId lookup which does not have a good performance. So I can conclude that index seek is only beneficial if the data is already covered by the index. is that correct?

Comment: "Key/RId lookup which does not have a good performance" - so, the system uses a nice, narrow index to isolate a single row and then performs a lookup for that row. You think that's going to have worse performance than scanning the entire wide table?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, No I don't think so. I just read that it would be better be avoided by using cover index. but it is not always possible. is it?
So now my question is : is the process of fetching data rows after seeking the index key value which is accompanied by nested join is key lookup? sorry this might be obvious as well. but I need to get a firm understanding on these basics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct in your description but the conclusion is not correct.  It may still be faster to use the index anyway even if it has to go off to the table for the rest of it.  The data pages contain many fewer rows than the index so there's lots of extra I/O when scanning.  Generally the index will tend to give you benefits if it selects few rows even if it's not a great fit.

Comment: Thanks, so Key Lookup is not bad as it might be needed in some scenarios. is the process of fetching data rows after seeking the index key value which is accompanied by nested join is called key lookup? sorry this might be obvious as well. but I need to get a firm understanding on these basics.

Comment: Also , I expect the key lookup to be used by query engine in many scenarios. is this correct? Well, I am asking this because apparently key lookup is notorious as I have searched the internet for it.

Comment: It's not really notorious, it just introduces a bit of extra I/O.  It's the only way to do it unless you build an entire index + covering columns for every query you're going to ever do.  You look at the index, then you go to the data pages.  That's a typical compromise.  Using an index to entirely answer your query is in fact atypical.

Comment: Thanks, I have marked it as answer. So a key lookup on clustered index, how is it different from a clustered index seek?

Comment: Searching the internet will also most likely make you think that for very similar reasons you should always have a PK that's an IDENTITY column and must be a clustered index.  It's nowhere near always true but you'll almost believe it by the time you've read the internet.

Comment: You are right mate, can you please answer my last question too?

Comment: A clustered index is basically the table organised by the data you specified.  Once you find the row you are looking for, the rest of the data is "just there".  If you go direct, you've no need to go anywhere else.  seeks and scans are the difference between having the key and having part of the key.  It's too big a subject for a tiny comment line.  There's plenty of explanations out there than will be better than mine.

Comment: We were discussing in chat the other day an example where an index scan was scanning 1K rows, then did a Key Lookup for these 1k rows. Performance was absolutely wonderful - compared to the previous plan that was doing a sort on 100M rows.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the data is not stored on the leaf level, the index will provide your database engine with a very exact location in the data pages where to look for the results.

I.e. instead of browsing all of your table's data pages for relevant data, your index seek first browses fewer and smaller pages, ideally with a hierarchy (so that it browses even fewer).

As a result you get a number of locators, which will admittedly have to be looked up from the complete set of (unsorted) data pages, but since you're looking up a specific page and location every time, it's still reasonably fast.